# is tbb::thread still in TBB-4.x?

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb

I have just read the document of the latest TBB's documents.
I can't find any information about tbb::thread, but I saw some information about mutex.

BTW, if TBB-4.x have thread library please help me find the resources of using tbb threads.
Please don't recommend the official documents, they are lack of examples.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was no `tbb::thread` but there was a `tbb::tbb_thread`, now deprecated. You can find it [here](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/appendices/compatibility_features/tbb_thread_cls.htm). Doc says:

> Intel® Threading Building Blocks (Intel® TBB) 3.0 introduces a header **[tbb/compat/thread](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/threads/thread_cls.htm)** that defines class **std::thread**. Prior versions had a header tbb/tbb_thread.h that defined class tbb_thread. The old header and names are still available, but deprecated in favor of the replacements...

TBB provides tbb/compat/ features for sake of compilers which lack C++11 support. The thread class was designed to be as close to `std::thread` or rather to `boost::thread` (at the time of introduction) as possible, thus you can refer to examples provided for these two if TBB documentation is not satisfactory.

You can also try `tbb\examples\task_priority\fractal` example which demonstrates usage of the thread class.